# Showing $f$ is convex

Tags: real-analysis

We say that $f:I \to [a,b]$ is convex if for every $x_1,x_2 \in I$,  and every $\lambda \in (0,1)$ we have $$f(\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2) \leq \lambda f(x_1) + (1 - \lambda)f(x_2)$$ I must show that $f$ is convex iff for every $x_1,x_2,x_3 \in I $ where $x_1 < x_2 <x_3$ we have $$\frac{f(x_2) - f(x_1)}{x_2 - x_1} \leq \frac{f(x_3) - f(x_2)}{x_3 - x_2}$$

Does anyone have ideas on how to go about showing this? I was going to seeing what we would get proving the "left" direction, but we don't have an actual function to work with. I'm not sure how we would show the "right" direction either.

Answer (score 0):

You can just apply the definition with
$$\lambda=\frac{x_3-x_2}{x_3-x_1}$$
and initial and final points $x_1$ and $x_3$ respectively i.e.
$$f(x_2)=f(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_3)\leq \frac{x_3-x_2}{x_3-x_1}f(x_1)+\frac{x_2-x_1}{x_3-x_1}f(x_3)$$
A little algebra and you are done.

Comment: Could you please explain the idea behind this choice of $\lambda$?